# Application stops when add custom View component

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I tried to create a clock in Android Studio using Kotlin.
I created a View with clock you can see code down.

```
class ClockView(c: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?, defStyleAttr: Int) : View(c, attrs, defStyleAttr) {
    private val paint = Paint()

    init {
        paint.color = Color.BLACK
        paint.style = Paint.Style.FILL
        paint.textSize = 60F
        paint.isAntiAlias = true
    }

    override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas?) {
        val calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
        val hour: String = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY).toString()
        val minute: String = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE).toString()
        val second: String = calendar.get(Calendar.SECOND).toString()

        canvas?.drawColor(Color.WHITE)
        canvas?.drawText(hour, width / 2F - 200F, height / 2F, paint)
        canvas?.drawText(minute, width / 2F - 100F, height / 2F, paint)
        canvas?.drawText(second, width / 2F, height / 2F, paint)

        postInvalidateDelayed(500)
        invalidate()

        super.onDraw(canvas)
    }
}
```

And I implemented it to my MainActivity XML file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

   <com.example.adnroid_clock.ClockView
       android:id="@+id/ClockView"
       android:layout_width="304dp"
       android:layout_height="243dp"
       app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
       app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
       app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.495"
       app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
       app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
       app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.157" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I launched application an got that error.[image: Run log]

Comment: You have a typo somewhere, `Dwidget` instead of `widget`

Comment: Please post stack traces in text, rather than screenshots!

Comment: Ok, so i edited and i write widget instead of widget but it's still doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The stack trace says that you use `androidx.constraintlayout.Dwidget.ConstraintLayout` (notice the `D` between the `.` and the `widget`) in some layout file. Presumably, that is your activity's layout file, given how the stack trace is set up.

Regardless, find the layout with this extra `D`, and remove the `D`.